# How do I export as an FBX with colors?

Tags: export, texture-painting, color, .fbx

*Disclaimer:  I am not an artist.*

I created a model in blender.  I switched my mode to "Texture Paint".  I painted the model.  When I export as an FBX or switch back to "Object Mode", my paint goes away.  I am opening my FBX View 3D, a native Windows 3D model viewer.

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures. As long as you saved the texture you painted on it will be accessible for setting up material, either in Blender (if for rendering) or in 3-d party application. If the latter then not much you can do in Blender except for exporting fbx and recreating material which will be using that saved texture in the 3-d party application / render engine.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look of the following image:

[image]

Please **Save as image** (so your edit become an external file on your drive as image) and  than add the Fake user by clicking the **F** button as high lighted.

I hope it will help :) good luck!

Comment: Or may be use a "Pack as PNG" option